# Why Android Studio always download gradle EVEN THOUGH I set GRADLE_HOME & GRADLE_USER_HOME properly

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am on windows 10 x64.
I download newest Android Studio 2.3 (162.xxxx). And I also have gradle(gradle-3.3-all) in d:\gradle-3.3-all.
I set enviroment as follow:

```
GRADLE_HOME=D:\gradle-3.3-all
GRADLE_USER_HOME=C:\Users\walfud\.gradle
PATH=... %GRADLE_HOME%\bin ....
```

But when I open my project first time, studio try to download gradle-3.3-all...

I'm sure I have the neccessary gradle and env in studio:
[image: env in as]
[image: proj setting]

---

What is more confused is that after Android Studio download gradle-3.3 in cache dir, all seems well untill I run `gradlew` in terminal..., like follow:
[image: gradlew]

WTF! Is it true that AS just downloaded the gradle just now?!

Anyone know what wrong?

Comment: New projects by default use the gradle wrapper.

Comment: @Henry Yes, I update the picture for my case. pls see it. I set the right version gradle in env, why not use my local gradle?

Comment: Because the gradle wrapper iognores any locally installed gradle. That's the whole point of the wrapper - making the build independent of locally installed software versions.

Comment: @walfud what is your project level setting for gradle, is it gradle wrapper or local gradle distribution ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I use gradle wrapper in module 'app'.

Comment: @Henry Disappointed... When clone from github, the first thing is change gradler wrapper properties to use local gradle, or it will be a long time to refresh...

Comment: Most people find it more convenient that they can build out of the box, without having to worry to install the correct gradle version first. This is especially true if you use some build server. If you don't want the wrapper, you can configure the project in AS not to use it. When building from the command line use `gradle` instead of `gradlew`.

Comment: @Henry Thanks Henry. You get me out out trouble